# Error building a project with Spring MVC dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a problem when building a default project created by NetBeans when Maven-Java Web application is created. When I add Spring MVC dependency under Properties->Framework category and build a project I get this error:

```
Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Did you try reading and understanding the error as it clearly shows what dependency is missing

Comment: It says that the dependency is missing in the central repository not in the pom file

Comment: Please note that in StackOverflow it is appreciated to  mark helpful answers as accepted. This way it helps other users with same issue, as well as it is nice to those who has helped you. I have noticed you never do...

Answer (score 1):

You have a placeholder in your local repo, try to delete this placeholder

delete the folder

```
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.0.1.RELEASE
```

Then rebuild with

```
mvn clean install -U
```

This assume your maven instillation is correct.

Comment: Still the same error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mavenproject2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.untitled:mavenproject2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: this is a different error, you are trying to download it as a jar, it is only available as a pom

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and throws you that error? Could be a missed library.

Comment: I already have this dependency and others automatically added by the NetBeans

Comment: Try to add the corresponding library. Search it in link below

https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

Comment: So there is no way to use pom file to automatically parse those libraries from the central repository?

Comment: If in the central repository doesn't exist the libraries (I reckon that is the Error), should to added manually

Comment: Before adding it manually, make sure u really need the spring bom in your dependencies.

Comment: Okay, I removed the dependency and the problem was solved

Comment: Well, it is not the solution to the problem, it is an issue with this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding it manually (or any other solution), make sure u really need the spring bom in your dependencies...

The bom should go under dependencyManagement section in your parent pom xml.

BTW the bom is only available as "POM" , not as "jar" scope.